# SQL Server 2008: BEGIN TRY and BEGIN TRANSACTION in CURSOR

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to loop through a number of records and process each of them. The cursor should continue looping through the records even if an ERROR occurs in processing, but at the end of the batch, I would like to see the error messages of ALL records which produced errors.

I have the following code:

FOR SELECT....

```
    OPEN cur
    FETCH next FROM cur INTO
    @some_variables
    WHILE @@fetch_status = 0
    BEGIN

    BEGIN TRY
      BEGIN TRANSACTION
        ...process the record...
      COMMIT
    END TRY

   BEGIN CATCH
   ROLLBACK

     RAISERROR ('%s',16, 1, @variable_containing_error)

    END CATCH
    END

            FETCH next FROM cur INTO
           @some_variables


    CLOSE cur
    DEALLOCATE cur
```

If I process two records, both with errors, I only get the first error message and not the second records error message.

I am not sure if I am using the BEGIN TRY and TRANSACTION commands properly.

Can someone please help?

Comment: Do you really need a cursor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try with out the transaction when you do rollback it is stopping your code try this:

```
While @@Fetch_Status=0
Begin
    Begin Try
        <You code goes here>        
    End Try
    Begin Catch
        RAISERROR ('%s',16, 1, @variable_containin_gerror)
    End Catch

    FETCH next FROM cur INTO
       @some_variables
End
```

Making this code I see an error you have:

You are closing your cursor before doing the fetch Next from. Also, you should try put the last end after the last fetch next from.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the error severity of 16 terminating your batch.

Try doing something like this:

```
DECLARE @error_status BIT
SET @error_status = CONVERT(BIT, 0)

OPEN cur
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @some_variables
WHILE @@fetch_status = 0
    BEGIN

        BEGIN TRY
            BEGIN TRANSACTION
            /*...process the record...*/
            COMMIT
        END TRY

        BEGIN CATCH
            ROLLBACK

            RAISERROR ('%s',1, 1, @variable_containing_error)
            SET @error_status = CONVERT(BIT, 1)

        END CATCH
    END

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @some_variables

CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur

IF @error_status = CONVERT(BIT, 1)
    RAISERROR ('See preceding errors(s).',16, 1)
```

Here I use a lower severity to print the error messages, but if an error is thrown, I raise a severity level 16 at the conclusion of the batch.